# Internal server error 500 with new rule in .htaccess in Prestashop

Tags: php, .htaccess, prestashop

I try to put a new rule in my .htaccess to redirect when some url appears, I put the following rule in the top of the .htaccess to preserve the content in case of it's regenerated again.

```
RewriteRule ^webservice/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}api/test.php [QSA,L]
```

I created too a new **/api** directory under the root folder and inside it a **test.php** with the following stamement :

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
```

but I always get the 500 Internal Server Error.

But if I change the directory to one of the defaults of Prestashop, (e.g **/webservice**) and create a new php like the above it's work perfectly when I make the request.

I check all the permissions in the directory and everything its fine.

In the error log appears the following error:

`Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your error log to see what the actual error is.

Comment: Why do you use `%{ENV:REWRITEBASE}`? Try to write the rule without it.

Comment: @sємsєм Yes it's work fine. Why is that?? I use it because I saw that Prestashop use it in it's .htaccess. Please make a proper answer to accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong REWRITEBASE may leads to such issues, so try to remove `%{ENV:REWRITEBASE}` from your rule to be:

```
RewriteRule ^webservice/?(.*)$ api/test.php [QSA,L]
```